# Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined at (index) - Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, node-modules

After updating my angular version, i am getting errors in my console and that my application wouldn't run although my terminal is error free. Any help on how to resolve this issue? I have been at this error for days trying to resolve it. Thank you

[image]

error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css 
localhost/:18 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css 
localhost/:24 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js 
localhost/:25 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
localhost/:26 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 
localhost/:27 GET http://localhost:4200/systemjs.config.js 
(index):11 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css 
(index):18 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css 
(index):21 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css 
(index):24 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js 
(index):25 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
(index):26 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 
(index):27 GET http://localhost:4200/systemjs.config.js 
(index):29 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at (index):29
(anonymous) @ (index):29
VM5452:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.43.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:15:17)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.43.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:12:7)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.43.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:13:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.43.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.512 (tbootstrap.min.js?8ede:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 10a724a…:52)
    at Object.1192 (scripts.bundle.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 10a724a…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 10a724a…:23)
(anonymous) @ VM5452:15
(anonymous) @ VM5452:12
(anonymous) @ VM5452:13
webpackJsonp.43.module.exports @ addScript.js:9
512 @ tbootstrap.min.js?8ede:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 10a724a…:52
1192 @ scripts.bundle.js:9
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 10a724a…:52
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 10a724a…:23
(anonymous) @ scripts.bundle.js:1
zone.js:1960 GET http://localhost:4200/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:1960
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:349
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:192
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:206
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1984
send @ VM5473:3
ResourceLoaderImpl.get @ resource_loader_impl.js:44
DirectiveNormalizer._fetch @ directive_normalizer.js:67
(anonymous) @ directive_normalizer.js:184
DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets @ directive_normalizer.js:184
DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeExternalStylesheets @ directive_normalizer.js:161
(anonymous) @ directive_normalizer.js:96
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:330
Zone.run @ zone.js:126
(anonymous) @ zone.js:679
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:363
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:166
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:529
zone.js:1960 GET http://localhost:4200/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:1960
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:349
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:192
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:206
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1984
send @ VM5473:3
ResourceLoaderImpl.get @ resource_loader_impl.js:44
DirectiveNormalizer._fetch @ directive_normalizer.js:67
(anonymous) @ directive_normalizer.js:184
DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets @ directive_normalizer.js:184
DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeExternalStylesheets @ directive_normalizer.js:161
(anonymous) @ directive_normalizer.js:96
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:330
Zone.run @ zone.js:126
(anonymous) @ zone.js:679
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:363
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:166
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:529
zone.js:1960 GET http://localhost:4200/css/local.css 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:1960
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:349
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:192
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:206
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1984
send @ VM5473:3
ResourceLoaderImpl.get @ resource_loader_impl.js:44
DirectiveNormalizer._fetch @ directive_normalizer.js:67
(anonymous) @ directive_normalizer.js:184
DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets @ directive_normalizer.js:184
DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeExternalStylesheets @ directive_normalizer.js:161
(anonymous) @ directive_normalizer.js:96
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:330
Zone.run @ zone.js:126
(anonymous) @ zone.js:679
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:363
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:166
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:529
zone.js:516 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css undefined
consoleError @ zone.js:516
_loop_1 @ zone.js:545
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:549
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
zone.js:518 ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
    at resolvePromis…, rejection: "Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask}
```

Index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Directory</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/js/jquery.min.js">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <!script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <!script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <!--script src="../systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.script('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
  </script>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined` which means you havent define System.

Comment: Can you share your index.html file?

Comment: @Smit , file added

Comment: i have updated my answer. Please replace your html completetly with the below html. It should fix all the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Your script src is going one level up in the root `../systemjs.config.js` where it should be only `systemjs.config.js`

Index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Directory</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/js/jquery.min.js">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you may look at [getting started of angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) or just [clone](https://github.com/shah-smit/Angular2-getting-started) this copy

Make Sure to have index.html and systemjs.config.js on the **same root** of the folder.

Comment: Yes i did just that

Comment: yeah it is giving me the same errors above. what version of angular are you using?

Comment: @Switz Can you share your `index.html` file?

Comment: Still the same error... Server could not load resources

Comment: after you updated angular did you perform `npm install`

Comment: Yeah i did that to install the node_modules

Comment: Can you update your error img. Because I am 100% sure now that above error img shouldnt be coming.